# Swift / tableView pass data with instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, swift, backendless

I have an array of BackendlessUsers filled within a tableView. How can I pass the user within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath function?

```
var deejays: [BackendlessUser] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")
    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    **let user = deejays[indexPath.row]**
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DJProfileAsUserVC") as! DJProfileAsUserVC

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a *var user: DJProfileAsUserVC!*  in DJProfileAsUserVC and after that to this:

```
let user = deejays[indexPath.row]
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("DJProfileAsUserVC") as! DJProfileAsUserVC
vc.user = user
```

Comment: @property in swift? :/

Comment: Done. Let me know if this is what you want.